# jquery code block only successful once

Tags: jquery, post

I have written the following jquery code block. When a postcode is changed on my site this code is run but it only works fully the first time the postcode is changed. I have put three alerts in the code. When the code block has been run once I don't get as far as the third alert. Am i doing something wrong?

```
$('#postcodefield').change(function(){
    var newPC = $(this).val()
    var areaData = null;
    var MAPITURL = "http://mapit.mysociety.org/postcode/";
    var postcodeUrl = MAPITURL + newPC;

    $('#gpQueryTerm').val(newPC);

    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        async: false,
        url : postcodeUrl,
        dataType : 'json',
        error: function(){
            $('input[name=town]').val(6);
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert('1');
            areaData = data;
            alert('2');
            // Extract the ward number
            ward = areaData.shortcuts.ward;
            wardCode = areaData.areas[ward].codes.ons;
            // now we have the ons, get the townsend value from the db
            alert('3');
            $.post("/tasks/getTownsend.cfm", {
                code: wardCode
            }, function(data){
                $('input[name=town]').val(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

James

Comment: No, i'm looking in the console and there are no errors?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugging tool like Firebug or Fiddler to look at the requests being sent and the responses coming back?

Comment: Yeah, I've used firebug. On the second attempt the post is ont sent?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it. Is it executing the `change` method the second time?

Comment: How is the postcode being changed?  Are you manually typing a new value each time, or is it being changed programatically?

Comment: yeah, it run the code up to the second alert but then stops without any error messages.

Comment: The postcode is being manually typed each time

Comment: How do you know its definitely not making the request? Perhaps the `.post` method is still expecting a `json` response because it's nested within the other.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I think I've got it sussed. For the secound postcode I was using 'areaData.shortcuts.ward' was not being retuned as a string but as an object. is there a way to test if a variable is a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the third alert is never being called then there must be an error with:

```
ward = areaData.shortcuts.ward;
wardCode = areaData.areas[ward].codes.ons;
```

Given the data in the question that's the most detailed answer I can give. I suggest you take a look at the JSON response and make sure it's what you expect it to be.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I've got it sussed. For the secound postcode I was using 'areaData.shortcuts.ward' was not being retuned as a string but as an object. is there a way to test if a variable is a string?

Comment: @JamesPrivett Yes, you can do `if(obj typeof 'string')`